# What is the difference between $ and ~?

Tags: jsoup

What is the difference between

```
doc.select("img[src$=.png");
```

and

```
doc.select("img[src~=.png");
```

I used both statements on same page and got different results i can't understand why,  both in the end looking for img src with png format but still very different results...
below is the code i was running:

```
Document doc;
try {
    //get all images
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tumor+").get();

            Elements images = doc.select("img[src$=.png");
            Elements images1 = doc.select("img[src~=.png");

            for (Element image : images) {
                    System.out.println("\nsrc : " + image.attr("src"));
                    System.out.println("height : " + image.attr("height"));
                    System.out.println("width : " + image.attr("width"));
                    System.out.println("alt : " + image.attr("alt"));
            }

            for (Element image1 : images1) {
                    System.out.println("\nsrc : " + image1.attr("src"));
                    System.out.println("height : " + image1.attr("height"));
                    System.out.println("width : " + image1.attr("width"));
                    System.out.println("alt : " + image1.attr("alt"));
            }

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc.select("img[src$=.png]");` means that you want to select values that **end** with `.png`.

`doc.select("img[src~=.png]");` means that you want to select values that **match the given regex**. In your example the regex is `.png`, i.e. *any character* (`.`) followed by `png`. As it is not specified it can match anywhere in the value.

So these are all valid values to match your regex:

- http://www.example.com/hallo.png (**.png** matches here)
- http://www.mypng.com/blubb (**ypng** matches here)
- http://www.example.com/foopng/bar.jpg (**opng** matches here)

So I guess that the second one matches for at least one URL that contains "png" somewhere.